# Can a context menu item be added to all application icons at once in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: .desktop, gnome-dash

I'm aware that actions can be added to individual icons by modifying the appropriate .desktop file, but I'd like to know if it is possible to add context menu items to *every* application icon. In particular, I'd like to add an option to open the appropriate .desktop file in a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot as such. Still, you could achieve this by adding a section to individual `.desktop` files. That could be automated using a script that finds all `.desktop` launchers on the system that populate the menu (i.e., in any "application" directories under the paths included in XDG_DATA_DIRS), copies them to `~/local/share/applications` then edits these copies (preferably using a stream editor like `sed`).